# CakePHP save model and associated model

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-model

I have a User model.

It has register view containing a form that looks like this:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User',array(NULL,NULL,'class' => 'signinform'));
echo $this->Form->input('first_name');
...
echo $this->Form->end('Create Account');
```

When you submit the form, it saves like this:

```
$this->User->save($this->data)
```

This works.

---

I added a table to my database called `addresses` with the field `user_id` that is a foreign key to `users.id`

I put in my Users model:

```
var $hasMany = 'Address';
```

I add fields like this to the register form:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Address.city');
```

I expected this to create a new entry into the addresses table and associate it with the new user. It does not, It creates a new user, but puts nothing in the addresses table.

I tried changing the save function from `save` to `saveAll`:

```
$this->User->saveAll($this->data)
```

Now nothing gets saved.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CakePHP saving needs a bit more work to save like that across relationships. Here's [an example from the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/75/Saving-Your-Data#Saving-Related-Model-Data-hasOne-hasMany-belongsTo-84).

```
<?php
function add() {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        // We can save the User data:
        // it should be in $this->data['User']

        $user = $this->User->save($this->data);

        // If the user was saved, Now we add this information to the data
        // and save the Profile.

        if (!empty($user)) {
            // The ID of the newly created user has been set
            // as $this->User->id.
            $this->data['Profile']['user_id'] = $this->User->id;

            // Because our User hasOne Profile, we can access
            // the Profile model through the User model:
            $this->User->Profile->save($this->data);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

When you make more than one database change, you should consider [using transactions](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1633/Transactions) to make them succeed or fail together. If you don't want to use transactions, consider what you will display to the user when the request fails part way through. Also consider what state the database will be left in, and how you can recover.

Comment: This works, but begs the question: If saving the user succeeds, but saving the address/profile fails — what to do? Taking them back to the form will try to create a new user again.

Comment: If that happens, @John, I would redirect them to a screen for editing the user they just created, and display the error as a flash message. Alternatively, you can use a transaction so that both inserts succeed or fail together: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1633/Transactions

Answer (score 1):

You might also need to put this in the Address model:

`var $belongsTo = 'User';`